# Jquery Datatable not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, datatable, datatables

I have created a query table using data from json.
I am trying to combine two column values in one 
but i always get undefined data when i try to combine two columns. 
I am not sure what is wrong here.

```
     not sure what is wrong here 

      $("#submit").click(function(){         
    var dataTableExample = $('#tbl_jad').DataTable();  
     $('#tbl_jad').show();
    if (dataTableExample != 'undefined') {  
        dataTableExample.destroy();  
    }

    dataTableExample =
     $('#tbl_jad').DataTable({  
        "aaData": data.d.results, 
        "aoColumns": [
        {  
            "mData": "ID"  
        },             
        {  
            "mData": "Position_x0020_Number",
        },
        {  
            "mData": "Title"  
        }, {  
            "mData": "Type_x0020_of_x0020_Action"  
        }, {  
            "mData": "Series"

        }]
        ,
    "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                      return data +' ('+ row[0]+')';
            },
            "targets": 1
        },
        { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 0 ] }
    ] 

    });     
}  
});
```

Comment: Have you tried  `return data +' (' + row.ID +')'`; ...? A little bit hard when we dont know the JSON.

Comment: i get the id of the row like 1,2,3,4,5,6 but i need the column data value

Comment: You know what that was my stupidity to height i did this and i got the column  value   *********return data +' ('+ row["ID"]+')' **** and i get the value of the column ID

Answer (score 0):

**return data +' ('+ row["ID"]+')'**

where ID is the column heading or column name